# Serializing Object Array Property Values

Tags: c#

Take the following program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var records = new Person[]
        {
            new Person{ FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 32 },
            new Person{ FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", Age = 27 },
            new Person{ FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "College", Age = 28 }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", records.Select(r => new
        {
            FullName = r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName
        })));
    }
}
```

Its **expected output** is:

`John Doe, Jane Doe, Joe College`

But its **actual output** is:

`{ FullName = John Doe }, { FullName = Jane Doe }, { FullName = Joe College }`

Is it possible to resolve this *from inside* the `WriteLine`?

This is a simplification of a bigger problem I recently encountered, and I need to resolve this from inside the `WriteLine` because I am performing this "serialization" inside a query; I cannot execute more than one statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of selecting anonymous type use:

```
records.Select(r =>  r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName)
```

So your `Console.WriteLine` could be:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", records.Select(r => r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName)));
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick and simple. Thank you. I apologize for asking such a simple question!

Comment: @JosuéMolina, you are welcome, and don't worry about the question being simple, you got so many alternatives now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", records.Select(r => String.Format("{0} {1}", r.FirstName, r.LastName) ));
```

Comment: `string.Format` is considerably less efficient than a simple concatenation due to the need to do a replace. It will definitely work, but should be avoided in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating a dynamic object.  I think you meant something like this:

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", records.Select(r => r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use inline lambda expression as below:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", records.Select(r => r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a ToString() method. This makes the approach more clean.

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
    }
}
```

and then

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", records.Select(r => r.ToString())));
```